# Get Number of Times Coupon Code is Used in Magento

Tags: magento

How can i get number of times the coupon code is used and list of coupon codes.Is that information available in `SalesRule` module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Quite easily in fact:

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
$coupon->load('SOMECOUPONCODE', 'code');
if($coupon->getId()) {
    $timesUsed = $coupon->getTimesUsed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Will try that!Where is the `$load` function located.

Comment: @blakcaps: it is part of any business model in magento (abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Abstract)

Comment: can we get order id also @DanielSloof